# Laravel 5.5: Entrust This cache store does not support tagging?

Tags: caching, laravel-5.5, entrust

I am using [Entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) (`zizaco/entrust": "5.2.x-dev`) for user roles and permissions, everything was working using `CACHE_DRIVER=array`.

But I have another requirement to lock user on  5 failed login attempts to use that feature I must have to change cache driver to `CACHE_DRIVER=file` and Entrust does not works on `file` driver, because `file` does not support tags.

Also I don't have choice to use other cache drivers `memcached`, `apc`, `redis` .. etc

is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks,

Kaleem